# Missing InResponseTo SAML attribute in SP initiated Okta sign on

Tags: saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to add a new service to an existing Okta setup. The service relies on SAML for authentication and uses strict checking of SAML messages.

When Okta session state is already present in the browser, everything works fine. Okta SAML response contains all the necessary attributes to get verified and everything just works.

However, when using a "clean" browser to initiate a new session, my service can not properly validate the Okta SAML response. The response is valid and properly signed, but is missing the `InResponseTo` attribute which is required for strict verification.

I wonder if somebody may have encountered an issue like that before? May there be some hidden setting in Okta or some common setup mistake in the authentication provider?

Answer (score 0):

Your service is complaining about the sequence of steps you use to initiate the SSO flow. In a so-called service provider-initiated SSO flow, you click on a link that goes to your service. Your service acting as a SAML service provider (SP) then sends a SAML authentication request to the identity provider (Okta) which then responds to this request with a SAML response. Since the identity provider is responding to the request from a service provider, the SAML response will contain an InResponseTo element.

How do you fix this? This is all about your service rather than Okta. You need to determine the correct URL and/or format of the request to your service that will cause it to fire a SAML authentication request to the identity provider.

See [Okta docs](https://www.okta.com/integrate/documentation/saml/#understanding-sp-initiated-login-flow) for more info

Comment: I'm afraid you have not read my question carefully. What I am trying to resolve is a difference in behavior related to the Okta session state as seen by browser (established vs new). Note, that even in a later case I am getting a proper SAML response (signed and valid), only one particular attribute is inexplicably missing.

Comment: @oakad The InResponse element is added by the identity provider (Okta) only when it receives an authentication request from the service provider. Please read the docs.

Comment: It is receiving the request from the SP. It's an SP initiated sign in.